# Reuse an interaction in any sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise, enterprise-architect

Do you have any idea how to reuse an interaction in more than one sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect?

[image]

In this case, I'd like to reuse the interaction ServiceX in different sequence diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You must not do that. A message is only part of the diagram it is placed on and used in the very context you show on that specific SD. The same applies for the life lines. They are all instances of classes and never re-used in other SDs.

Actually you derive the message from an operation defined in the class that instantiates your object. Just choose the right one from the message drop down.

[image]

As you can see, `Class1` is the classifier of `Object1` and its `operation` is available in the dropdown.